# High Glucose vs Low Glucose DMEM for Cell Culture

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-culture

I've noticed that in mammalian cell culture, there are often two types of DMEM available. High Glucose and Low Glucose. Does it matter which type I use for culturing of cells (e.g. Hela or HEK293)? Which is the type people normally use?

Answer (score 2):

We typically use High Glucose as cells grow faster.  One caveat is that there are concerns that certain protein modifications (specifically OGlnAc-ylation) may be upregulated in non-physiological (25mM or high glucose) media.